# Which pairs do you need to add to the relation such that it satisfies following properties..?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

> Given is the relation $R := \left\{(b,a), (b,b), (b,c), (c,a),
> (c,c)\right\}$ over the set $A := \left\{a,b,c,d\right\}$. Which pairs
>   $(x,y) \in A \times A$ you at least need to add to $R$ such that $R$
>   is
>
> (i) reflexive
>
> (ii) antisymmetric
>
> (iii) connex

(i) You need to add the pair $(a,a)$

(ii) A relation is antisymmetric if $\forall x,y \in A: xRy \wedge yRx \Rightarrow x=y$. But that relation is already antisymmetric, so we don't need to add any pairs.

(iii) A relation is connex, if $\forall x,y \in A: (x,y) \in R \vee (y,x) \in R $ or $x=y$.

So as it looks like, this relation is also already connex, we don't need to add any pairs.. :o

---

I'm a bit confused. We need to add pairs to $R$ such that it satisfies these properties (as less pairs as possible added). So we really just need to look at $R$ itself, right? Or do I also need to take care of element $d$ because it occurs in set $A$?

Did I do it correctly? If some relations are unknown to you (maybe the connex), assume that my definition is correct.

Comment: Notice that $A=\{a,b,c,\color{red}{d}\}$.  For (i) you need *every* element in $A$ to be related to itself.  Yes, $(a,a)$ needed to be added, but what about $d$?  It doesn't make sense to ask (ii) as it's own individual question as you would *never* need to add more pairs to a relation, only potentially remove pairs, so it appears as though the question is actually all one.  As such, we'll just keep (ii) in the back of our mind for when we continue.  For (iii), again I point out that $d$ is an element of $A$.  You need at least one of $(a,d)$ or $(d,a)$ in the relation and so on...

Comment: If $A$ would have been equal to $\{a,b,c\}$ then you are correct that you only needed to add $(a,a)$ and then you would be done, but again $A$ *also* contains $d$.

Comment: @JMoravitz For symmetry, I would also need to take care of d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to care about the unused element $d$.

(i)  Regarding to the definition of reflexivity of $R$, we need $\forall x\in A:\,(x,x)\in R$. 
In particular, as $d\in A$, we also need to add $(d,d)$ to $R$ besides $(a,a)$ in order to obtain a reflexive relation.

(ii)  Correct. 
$R$ remains antisymmetric if we add more elements to the base set (with no relation).

(iii)  We need to deal with $d$, it has to relate to all other elements somehow in the extended relation. 
 
So we need to add at least $3$ pairs, but these are not uniquely determined. We might choose to put $d$ 'on the top', i.e. to add the pairs $(a,d),\ (b,d)$ and $(c,d)$.